# Xamarin Android pop async not closing instances properly

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing one android application using Xamarin Android. For navigation, I am using push async and pop async. this application I am developing for RFID reading. When I click on the back button I am removing the page from the navigation stack. When I click the back button it is coming to the previous screen. But that instance is not closing properly.

If I am going to another screen and scanning RFID then it is reading in current as well as previous pages also (using await `UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync` to display scanned RFID value) which is showing multiple times).

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you `await`ing the call to `Navigation.PopAsync();`? You have to, or else you'll get what you're experiencing.

Comment: i am using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Navigation.PopAsync());

Comment: Could you provide the code for us to reproduce? Which back button you used for? The back button of the page on the top left? Or the back button on device menu?